# sqlsrv_prepare(): must be of type resource, bool given php_sqlsrv 80

Tags: php, sql-server, database

So after updating my PHP from PHP 7 to PHP 8.
I also imported an extension called `php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll`.

I now receive the following error

> sqlsrv_prepare(): must be of type resource, bool given.

The line in question according to the error log is:

```
$rs=sqlsrv_prepare($cnms,$sql)
```

Also  'cnms' is as a function in the following way:

```
function cnms($isSched){

        if($isSched)
            $c = array( "Database"=>"test_db", "UID"=>"test_user", "PWD"=>"*****");
        else
            $c = array( "Database"=>"test_db", "UID"=>"dppadmin","PWD"=>"****");

        $cnms=sqlsrv_connect("test_svr",$c);
        //  $cnms=sqlsrv_connect("192.168.1.1",$c);

        if($cnms===false)
            echo("test_svr connect fail");
            // print_r( sqlsrv_errors());
        return $cnms;
```

I assume the `php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll` extension has a different way of reading the `sqlsrv_prepare()`.

Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: The error most likely means that `$cnms` is `false` when it should be a connection object.

Comment: The error message is telling you that you're passing a boolean to the function; you say that the variable (the boolean) is coming from this function; and you have a line right there checking for false, and a commented out line below it which would tell you what the error was. The only problem with that line is that it's indented like it's part of the if statement, but will actually run every time, because you didn't use `{` and `}`.

Comment: The `$cnms` is clearly `false` which means your connection attempt failed. You need to debug it. Something like `if( !$cnms ){  echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));}`